# Need help about transfer from two table but copy all detail in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a question,  i have two diffrent table example

Table_data    Table_history.

the situation is,when new users register a form all the detail will be insert into table_data, then if the users want add a nominee  the detail is still  will be insert into table_data  and it will replace the detail with that user, and the information about the user in table_data will transfer to another table call table_history.

My question is,how i can transfer all the detail from table_data for the first useer into table_history .?after the nominee information is insert into table_data?

Answer (score 0):

I would do an INSERT INTO Table_history before I update Table_data

```
INSERT INTO Table_history (ColA, ColB, ...) 
VALUES (
(SELECT ColA FROM Table_data WHERE id = ... ),
(SELECT ColB FROM Table_data WHERE id = ... ), 
.... 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger for this situation.

The trigger should be created for after insert on table table_data.

Please refer to following link for complete reference.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
you may be have use identifier OLD to reference the current data in Table_data

Answer (score 0):

I din't get your question perfectly.
You can write a DB trigger to sense when user is adding nominee, Before insert, you can delete the record from Table_data table and insert it into Table_hostory table in trigger logic.

Comment: i want know ,how i can transfer information from one table to other table, after another user register for new registration?

Comment: You can write a cursor inside a trigger. Design DB in a way that there is a foreign key between these two tables. You can fetch records from different table using cursor and specifying the condition.